# Scaling of time to broadcast an operation on 3D arrays in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, broadcasting, numpy-ufunc

I am trying to broadcast a simple operation of ">" over two 3D arrays. One has dimensions (m, 1, n) the other (1, m, n). If I change the value of the third dimension (n), I would naively expect that the speed of the computation would scale as n.

However, when I try to measure this explicitly I find that there is an increase in computation time of about factor 10 when increasing n from 1 to 2, after which the scaling is linear.

Why does the computation time increase so drastically when going from n=1 to n=2? I'm assuming that it is an artifact of memory management in numpy but I'm looking for more specifics.

The code is attached below with the resulting plot.

```
import numpy as np
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def compute_time(n):

    x, y = (np.random.uniform(size=(1, 1000, n)), 
            np.random.uniform(size=(1000, 1, n)))

    t = time.time()
    x > y 
    return time.time() - t

a = [
        [
            n, np.asarray([compute_time(n) 
            for _ in range(100)]).mean()
        ]
        for n in range(1, 30, 1)
    ]

a = np.asarray(a)
plt.plot(a[:, 0], a[:, 1])
plt.xlabel('n')
plt.ylabel('time(ms)')
plt.show()
```

**Plot of time to broadcast an operation**

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I can't prove it but I am pretty certain that this is due to one simple optimization that is only available at n==1.

Currently, the numpy ufunc implementation is based on computergenerated code for the innermost loop which is mapped to a simple C loop. Enclosing loops require the use of a fully fledged iterator object which depending on the payload i.e. the size of the innermost loop and the cost of the atomic operation can be a significant overhead.

Now, at n==1 the problem is essentially 2D (numpy is smart enough to detect that), with innermost loop of size 1000, hence 1000 steps of the iterator object. From n==2 upwards the innermost loop has size n and we have 1,000,000 steps of the iterator object which accounts for the jump you are observing.

As I said I can't prove it but I can make it look plausible: If we move the variable dimension to the front, then the innermost loop has constant size of 1000, and the outer loop grows linearly in 1000 iteration steps. And indeed that makes the jump go away.

[image]

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def compute_time(n, axis=2):
    xs, ys = [1, 10], [10, 1]
    xs.insert(axis, n)
    ys.insert(axis, n)
    x, y = (np.random.uniform(size=xs),
            np.random.uniform(size=ys))

    t = time.perf_counter()
    x > y
    return time.perf_counter() - t

a = [
        [
            n,
            np.asarray([compute_time(n) for _ in range(100)]).mean(),
            np.asarray([compute_time(n, 0) for _ in range(100)]).mean()
        ]
        for n in range(0, 10, 1)
     ]

a = np.asarray(a)
plt.plot(a[:, 0], a[:, 1:])
plt.xlabel('n')
plt.ylabel('time(ms)')
plt.show()
```

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48257213/7207392

Answer (score 6):

@Paul's theory is quite right. In this answer I use `perf` and debugger to dive in in order to back this theory up.

First, let's take a look where there running time is spent (see listings for run.py bellow for the exact code).

For `n=1` we see the following:

```
Event count (approx.): 3388750000
Overhead  Command  Shared Object                               Symbol                                                               
  34,04%  python   umath.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so       [.] DOUBLE_less
  32,71%  python   multiarray.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so  [.] _aligned_strided_to_contig_size8_srcstride0
  28,16%  python   libc-2.23.so                                [.] __memmove_ssse3_back
   1,46%  python   multiarray.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so  [.] PyArray_TransferNDimToStrided
```

compared to `n=2`:

```
Event count (approx.): 28954250000                                                              
Overhead  Command  Shared Object                               Symbol                                                               
  40,85%  python   libc-2.23.so                                [.] __memmove_ssse3_back
  40,16%  python   multiarray.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so  [.] PyArray_TransferNDimToStrided
   8,61%  python   umath.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so       [.] DOUBLE_less
   8,41%  python   multiarray.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so  [.] _contig_to_contig
```

For n=2, there are 8.5 times more events counted, but only for twice the data, so we need to explain the slowdown-factor of 4.

Another important observation: the running time is dominated by memory-operations for `n=2` and (less obvious) also for `n=1` (`_aligned_strided_to_contig_size8_srcstride0` is all about copying data), they overweight the costs for comparison - `DOUBLE_less`.

Obviously, [`PyArray_TransferNDimtoStrided`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/4a7926f7085482a5f1f3669715ca20d20f12099a/numpy/core/src/multiarray/lowlevel_strided_loops.c.src#L980) is called for both sizes, so why is there such a great difference in its share of the running time?

The shown self-time of `PyArray_TransferNDimtoStrided` isn't the time needed for copying, but the overhead: the pointers are adjusted, so that in the last dimension can be copied in one go via [`stransfer`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/4a7926f7085482a5f1f3669715ca20d20f12099a/numpy/core/src/multiarray/lowlevel_strided_loops.c.src#L1078):

```
 PyArray_TransferNDimToStrided(npy_intp ndim,
 ....
 /* A loop for dimensions 0 and 1 */
 for (i = 0; i < shape1; ++i) {
    if (shape0 >= count) {
        stransfer(dst, dst_stride, src, src_stride0,
                    count, src_itemsize, data);
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        stransfer(dst, dst_stride, src, src_stride0,
                    shape0, src_itemsize, data);
    }
    count -= shape0;
    src += src_stride1;
    dst += shape0*dst_stride;
}
...
```

These stransfer-functions are [`_aligned_strided_to_contig_size8_srcstride0`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/4a7926f7085482a5f1f3669715ca20d20f12099a/numpy/core/src/multiarray/lowlevel_strided_loops.c.src#L117) (see generated code in the listing further below) and [`_contig_to_contig`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/4a7926f7085482a5f1f3669715ca20d20f12099a/numpy/core/src/multiarray/lowlevel_strided_loops.c.src#L325):

- `_contig_to_contig` is used in case of `n=2` and tranfers 2-doubles (last dimension has 2 values), the overhead of adjusting the pointers is pretty high!
- `_aligned_strided_to_contig_size8_srcstride0` is used for `n=1` and transfers 1000 doubles per call (as @Paul pointed out and as we will see soon, numpy is clever enough to discard dimensions, which are 1-element long), the overhead of adjusting the pointers can be neglected.

Btw, these functions are used instead of a simple for-loop in order to use vectorization of modern CPUs: with stride known at compile time the compiler is able to vectorize the code (which compilers are often not able to do for strides only known at runtime), thus numpy analyzes the access pattern and dispatches to different precompiled functions.

One question left: Does numpy really discard last dimension, if its size is 1, as our observations suggest?

It is easy to verify with a debbuger:

- an ufunc access data via an iterator, which is created in [`iterator_loop`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/d2476fff1b22d96f6690650af6e52fae663f7413/numpy/core/src/umath/ufunc_object.c#L1466) via [`NpyIter_AdvancedNew`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/4a7926f7085482a5f1f3669715ca20d20f12099a/numpy/core/src/multiarray/nditer_constr.c#L104)
- [in `NpyIter_AdvancedNew`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/4a7926f7085482a5f1f3669715ca20d20f12099a/numpy/core/src/multiarray/nditer_constr.c#L416), the dimensions are analyzed (and reinterpreted) when [`npyiter_coalesce_axes`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/464f79eb1d05bf938d16b49da1c39a4e02506fa3/numpy/core/src/multiarray/nditer_api.c#L1622)

As for the speed-factor `4` which is "lost" when comparing `n=2` to `n=1`: It has no special meaning and is just a random value on my maschine: Changing the dimension of the matrix from 10^3 to 10^4 would shift the advantage even further (less overhead) even further to `n=1`-case, which leads on my machine to lost-speed-factor 12.

---

run.py

```
import sys
import numpy as np

n=int(sys.argv[1])

x, y = (np.random.uniform(size=(1, 1000, n)), 
        np.random.uniform(size=(1000, 1, n)))

for _ in range(10000):
    y<x
```

and then:

```
perf record python run.py 1
perf report
....
perf record python run.py 2
perf report
```

---

Generated source of `_aligned_strided_to_contig_size8_srcstride0`:

```
/*
 * specialized copy and swap for source stride 0,
 * interestingly unrolling here is like above is only marginally profitable for
 * small types and detrimental for >= 8byte moves on x86
 * but it profits from vectorization enabled with -O3
 */
#if (0 == 0) && 1
static NPY_GCC_OPT_3 void
_aligned_strided_to_contig_size8_srcstride0(char *dst,
                        npy_intp dst_stride,
                        char *src, npy_intp NPY_UNUSED(src_stride),
                        npy_intp N, npy_intp NPY_UNUSED(src_itemsize),
                        NpyAuxData *NPY_UNUSED(data))
{
#if 8 != 16
#  if !(8 == 1 && 1)
    npy_uint64 temp;
#  endif
#else
    npy_uint64 temp0, temp1;
#endif
    if (N == 0) {
        return;
    }
#if 1 && 8 != 16
    /* sanity check */
    assert(npy_is_aligned(dst, _ALIGN(npy_uint64)));
    assert(npy_is_aligned(src, _ALIGN(npy_uint64)));
#endif
#if 8 == 1 && 1
    memset(dst, *src, N);
#else

#  if 8 != 16
    temp = _NPY_NOP8(*((npy_uint64 *)src));
#  else
#    if 0 == 0
        temp0 = (*((npy_uint64 *)src));
        temp1 = (*((npy_uint64 *)src + 1));
#    elif 0 == 1
        temp0 = _NPY_SWAP8(*((npy_uint64 *)src + 1));
        temp1 = _NPY_SWAP8(*((npy_uint64 *)src));
#    elif 0 == 2
        temp0 = _NPY_SWAP8(*((npy_uint64 *)src));
        temp1 = _NPY_SWAP8(*((npy_uint64 *)src + 1));
#    endif
#  endif

    while (N > 0) {
#  if 8 != 16
        *((npy_uint64 *)dst) = temp;
#  else
        *((npy_uint64 *)dst) = temp0;
        *((npy_uint64 *)dst + 1) = temp1;
#  endif
#  if 1
        dst += 8;
#  else
        dst += dst_stride;
#  endif
        --N;
    }
#endif/* @elsize == 1 && 1 -- else */
}
#endif/* (0 == 0) && 1 */
```

Comment: A great answer; very educational, exactly what I was hoping for. I don't understand people are not upvoting this. I'll leave it featured one more day and award the bounty tomorrow.