# how to optimize iteration on exponential in numpy

Tags: loops, numpy, exponential, exponent

Say I have the following `numpy array`

```
n = 50
a = np.array(range(1, 1000)) / 1000.
```

I would like to execute this line of code

```
%timeit v = [a ** k for k in range(0, n)]
1000 loops, best of 3: 2.01 ms per loop
```

However, this line of code will ultimately be executed in a loop, therefore I have performance issues.

Is there a way to optimize the loop? For example, the result of a specific calculation `i` in the list comprehension is simply the result of the previous calculation result in the loop, multiplied by `a` again.

I don't mind storing the results in a 2d-array instead of arrays in a list. That would probably be cleaner. By the way, I also tried the following, but it yields similar performance results:

```
    k = np.array(range(0, n))
    ones = np.ones(n)
    temp = np.outer(a, ones)
```

And then performed the following calculation

```
%timeit temp ** k
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.96 ms per loop
```

or

```
%timeit np.power(temp, k)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.92 ms per loop
```

But both yields similar results to the list comprehension above. By the way, `n` will always be an `integer` in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In quick tests `cumprod` seems to be faster.

```
In [225]: timeit v = np.array([a ** k for k in range(0, n)])
2.76 ms ± 1.62 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [228]: %%timeit 
     ...: A=np.broadcast_to(a[:,None],(len(a),50))
     ...: v1=np.cumprod(A,axis=1)
     ...: 
208 µs ± 42.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

To compare values I have to tweak ranges, since `v` includes a 0 power, while `v1` starts with a 1 power:

```
In [224]: np.allclose(np.array(v)[1:], v1.T[:-1])
Out[224]: True
```

But the timings suggest that `cumprod` is worth refining.

The proposed duplicate was [Efficient way to compute the Vandermonde matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48245987/efficient-way-to-compute-the-vandermonde-matrix).  That still has good ideas.

Comment: Thanks, I used a mix from the np.vander and your answer to create what I needed. The truth is I kind of needed to calculate the Vadermonde matrix, but using your answer, I can do it faster. All I did in the end was to add the 1d array of ones to the first column:
`v1 = np.insert(v1, 0, np.ones(len(a)), axis=1)`