# Generating multiple vandermonde arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, linear-algebra

I have a function that creates a 2-dim array, a Vandermonde matrix and is called as:

`vandermonde(generator, rank)`

Where generator is a n-sized array for example

`generator = np.array([-1/2, 1/2, 3/2, 5/2, 7/2, 9/2])`

and `rank=4`

Then I need to create 4 Vandermonde matrices (because `rank=4`) skewed by `h` in my space (that `h` is arbitrary here, lets call `h=1`).

Therefore I came with the following deterministic code:

```
V = np.array([
        vandermonde(generator-0*h, rank),
        vandermonde(generator-1*h, rank),
        vandermonde(generator-2*h, rank),
        vandermonde(generator-3*h, rank)
        ])
```

Then I want instead do multiple manual calls to `vandermonde` I used a `for`-loop as in:

```
V=[]
for i in range(rank):
    V.append(vandermonde(generator - h*i, rank))
V = np.array(V)
```

This approach works fine, but seems too "patchy". I tried a `np.append` approach as below:

```
M = np.array([])
for i in range(rank):
    M = np.append(M,[vandermonde(generator - h*i, rank)])
```

But didn't worked as I expected, seems `np.append` expand the array instead to create a new element.

My questions are:

1. How can I not use standard Python lists, use directly a np approach cause `np.append` seems not behave as I expect, instead it just grow that array instead add a new array element
2. Is there any more direct numpy approaches to this?

My vandermonde function is:

```
def vandermonde(generator, rank=None):
    """Returns a vandermonde matrix

    If rank not passwd returns a square vandermonde matrix
    """

    if rank is None:
        rank = len(generator)

    return np.tile(generator,(rank,1)) ** np.array(range(rank)).reshape((rank,1))
```

The expected answer is a 3 dimensional array with size `(generator, rank, rank)` where each element is one of the generator skewed vandermonde matrices. For the constants above(`generator, rank, h`) we have:

```
V= array([[[  1.  ,   1.  ,   1.  ,   1.  ,   1.  ,   1.  ],
        [ -0.5 ,   0.5 ,   1.5 ,   2.5 ,   3.5 ,   4.5 ],
        [  0.25,   0.25,   2.25,   6.25,  12.25,  20.25],
        [ -0.12,   0.12,   3.38,  15.62,  42.88,  91.12]],

       [[  1.  ,   1.  ,   1.  ,   1.  ,   1.  ,   1.  ],
        [ -1.5 ,  -0.5 ,   0.5 ,   1.5 ,   2.5 ,   3.5 ],
        [  2.25,   0.25,   0.25,   2.25,   6.25,  12.25],
        [ -3.38,  -0.12,   0.12,   3.38,  15.62,  42.88]],

       [[  1.  ,   1.  ,   1.  ,   1.  ,   1.  ,   1.  ],
        [ -2.5 ,  -1.5 ,  -0.5 ,   0.5 ,   1.5 ,   2.5 ],
        [  6.25,   2.25,   0.25,   0.25,   2.25,   6.25],
        [-15.62,  -3.38,  -0.12,   0.12,   3.38,  15.62]],

       [[  1.  ,   1.  ,   1.  ,   1.  ,   1.  ,   1.  ],
        [ -3.5 ,  -2.5 ,  -1.5 ,  -0.5 ,   0.5 ,   1.5 ],
        [ 12.25,   6.25,   2.25,   0.25,   0.25,   2.25],
        [-42.88, -15.62,  -3.38,  -0.12,   0.12,   3.38]]])
```

---

Some related ideas can be found in this discussion on: [efficient-way-to-compute-the-vandermonde-matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48245987/efficient-way-to-compute-the-vandermonde-matrix/)

Comment: Share implementation of `vandermonde`?

Comment: @Divakar sure. Added.

Comment: ppl, just downvote for free? no comments added.

Comment: Numpy is efficient because it works with fix size arrays. The method `np.append` is no really efficient and is indeed expending an array (which means modification of the size => inneficient). To be efficient, you need to create an array at the right size before placing element into it. Since I do not completely get what the desired input / outputs are, it's hard to come up with a better proposition.

Comment: adding expected output and array dimensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) to get the final `3D` array in a vectorized manner -

```
r = np.arange(rank)
V_out = (generator - h*r[:,None,None]) ** r[:,None]
```

We can also use `cumprod` to achieve the exponential values for another solution -

```
gr = np.repeat(generator - h*r[:,None,None], rank, axis=1)
gr[:,0] = 1
out = gr.cumprod(1)
```

Comment: Seems master broadcasts is a must have.
I think that will even help me to rewrite the ```vandermonde``` function.

Comment: @Lin Yes, it will be : `(generator - h*i) ** np.arange(rank)[:,None]`.

Comment: @Lin This could be helpful as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48245987/efficient-way-to-compute-the-vandermonde-matrix

Comment: @kmario23 thank you, that really add some ideas to the problem.